# Web Service that converts address to lat/Long

Tags: vb.net, web-services, google-maps, geolocation

I was wondering if anyone knows of a good web service that I can supply an address and it returns a Lat/Long in decimal degrees? I have been trying to play with the `Google Maps API`, but I cannot find the documentation for using a desktop app(Winforms) to return the data. I have used both `WebClient` and the `WebRequest/WebResponse` ways without success. The error is '610:Invalid key' though I am staring at the key and just copy/pasted it into the parameters - including making a new one. It seems `Google` is not an easy route and I would like a diff option if poss. Any ideas would be great. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [**Google Geocoding API v3**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

*There is no separate things for Desktop application.* So you're looking exactly for this

> "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/**xml**?address=
>   **your encodedAddress**&sensor=false"

Here is a simple example I used in `C#`:

```
string address = "your address";
encodedAddress = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(address).Replace("+", "%20");
string googleApiURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/" + "xml?address=" + encodedAddress + "&sensor=false";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(googleApiURL);
request.Timeout = 10000;
request.Method = "GET";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
if (response != null)
{
                //Parse here to to capture the lat and long
}
else
{
                //Handle if don't get response
}
```

For you, it won't be difficult to convert it to `VB.NET`.

The major part here is how you are going to *parse the XML/JSON response*, As I already bold faced in URL

- Google provide two different response `xml` or `json`.
- Don't forget to encode the address.

**NOTE:** Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 requests per day.

Hope you got some idea.

Comment: @DonA I'm glad I was able to help.